# Any sample of MS BotFramework SDK4 app in ASP.NET MVC (not Core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, botframework

I need to integrate bot into our currently working ASP.NET MVC 5 app.
There are a lot of samples of creating bot using .NET Core, but nothing about ASP.NET MVC. There are samples of creating bot using MS Botframework SDK 3, but I need version 4.
Could you please give any link to the bot MS Botframework SDK 4 project using ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied the CoreBot and modified it to target netframework: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/CoreBot-ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub Microsoft provides a list of samples including the technology:
[BotBuilder-Samples list](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#samples-list)

e.g. [Basic bot template](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_webapi/13.basic-bot) which uses [AspNet.WebApi 5.2.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_webapi/13.basic-bot/packages.config)